# linux tail command

Tags: linux, logging

I am not sure this can be done, but with linux, you never know it's limits.

I am tailing an apache log:

```
\#tail -f apachelog.access-log
```

It gets me what I want, but I want to narrow down what it returns.  Here's a typical row I'll get:

```
2011-01-28T04:20:59-07:00 SERVER03 apache: 10.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2011:04:20:59 +0000] "POST /a/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4461 "http://somesite.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"
```

Is it possible to filter what I am tailing? 
At times, I'd like to only view the referring site.  And other times I'd like to view 2 or 3 other items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite easily execute:

```
tail -f apachelog.access-log | grep SERVER03
```

which will only give you lines containing the string `SERVER03`.

Answer (score 1):

Use tail to start.

```
$ tail -f logfile | grep 'PATTERN' | less -f
```

WHat I  usually do though is use `less`, then hit ^C to get the colon prompt.  Search or whatever.  Then type 'F' and less goes back to 'follow' mode.

Comment: I can't seem to get this series of commands to work properly. I see the output I expect up until I hit ^C. At this point, I can tell I'm in less and can search for things/navigate/etc. However I can't seem to get back into "follow" mode. 'F' puts less in follow mode, but the terminal doesn't update with new input from the log file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately ^C seems to kill the tail command so the results stop updating.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do it by cut command

Answer (score 0):

tail -f  file | egrep ...pattern...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view just one column of the log live, you should consider piping the `tail -f` output through `awk`, `sed`, or `perl`.  All of which would be better suited to a question on unix.stackexchange.com than SO.